# Accept a mutable collection with the promise of not changing it

Tags: scala, collections, parameter-passing

Normally if I want to "promise" in my method that I won't change the passed parameter, I would accept it as an immutable collection. However, I want to allow for the caller to pass a mutable collection, but still promise in my method that I won't change it anyway.

I'm talking specifically about IndexedSeq

Comment: Why don't you just use the trait `scala.collection.IndexedSeq`? In this way both the immutable and the mutable version can be passed and you can't accidently change the data, because the trait has no methods for it.

Comment: @Kigyo You should turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Most (if not all) collections, that have a mutable and an immutable version, have a common superclass.

In case of your `IndexedSeq` it is the trait `scala.collection.IndexedSeq`.

`def foo(seq: scala.collection.IndexedSeq) = ...`

would accept both `scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq` and `scala.collection.mutable.IndexedSeq`.

`scala.collection.IndexedSeq` also has no methods for modifying the collection.

**BUT** it is not a guarantee, because you can still do something like this:

```
def foo(seq: scala.collection.IndexedSeq) = seq match {
  case s: scala.collection.mutable.IndexedSeq => ... //use modifying methods on s
  case _ => ... //whatever
}
```

In the end you can still access methods that might change state. The advantage is that you have to (actively) match it, in order to get access to those methods. So you can only do it, when you are aware of it.

A promise? Depends on you..

Comment: Is this really how it is "normally" done? that's quite verbose and ugly

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It is very tedious to type collection.IndexedSeq[Int], mutable.IndexedSeq[Int], immutable.IndexedSeq[Int], etc

Comment: @Spacemonkey yes, that is how it is done. The beauty of Scala is that you only must to write the type once, and the compiler will be able to infer the type in the rest of the code where it can.

Comment: @Andrey "you only have to write the type once" well, actually then that's like any other language, you are not going to tell the compiler what the type is twice.

Comment: @Spacemonkey what I mean is that you can do this `val x = Seq(); val y = x`. But, for example in Java, you would need to `List<String> x = new LinkedList<String>(); List<String> y = x`.